# custom uitablecellcant connect tablecell to files owner

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I may be barking up the wrong tree but I'm trying to duplicate functionality I wrote for ios5 in a project thats been updated to ios7.

I've copied and pasted the code across, I get this error

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:5261
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier TableView - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30829f4b 0x3ac6a6af 0x30829e25 0x311d1fe3 0x3310891f 0x11bebf 0x330cea5b 0x33076e7d 0x33076699 0x32f9cda3 0x32c23c6b 0x32c1f47b 0x32c1f30d 0x32c1ed1f 0x32c1eb2f 0x32c1885d 0x307f51cd 0x307f2b71 0x307f2eb3 0x3075dc27 0x3075da0b 0x35484283 0x33001049 0x81597 0x7b558)
```

Everything is the same as another controller where it works except when I examine the xib

Working one:

[image]

Crashing one:

[image]

The difference being there no Referencing outlet tableCell -> File's Owner

HOW? WHY?

Here's the code just in case

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "blogCellVC.h"

@interface BlogsListingiPhoneVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> 
{
    NSArray *blogsListing;
    UITableView *tableView;
    IBOutlet blogCellVC *tableCell;
}
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *MyIndentifier = @"MyCell";

    blogCellVC *cell = (blogCellVC *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"blogCellVC" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = tableCell;
    }

    blogsListingModel *info = [_blogsListing objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


   if (info.blogActive == 0)
    {
        [cell cellHead:info.blogName];
        [cell cellHeadCol:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [cell cellIcon:@"blank.png"];

    }else { 
        [cell cellHead:info.blogName];
        [cell cellHeadCol:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [cell cellIcon:@"tick.png"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Customcell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface blogCellVC : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UILabel *cellHead;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *cellIcon;
}

- (void)cellHead:(NSString *)_text;
- (void)cellIcon:(NSString *)_text;
- (void)cellHeadCol:(UIColor *)aCol;

@end
```

Customcell.m

```
#import "blogCellVC.h"

@interface blogCellVC ()

@end

@implementation blogCellVC

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)cellHead:(NSString *)_text {
    cellHead.text = _text;
}

- (void)cellHeadCol:(UIColor *)aCol {
    cellHead.textColor = aCol;
    //cellStandfirst.textColor = aCol;
}

- (void)cellIcon:(NSString *)_text {
    cellIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_text];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

PS. I have set the custom class of the File's Owner in the Identity inspector to 'blogCellVC' and the identifier in the attributes inspector to 'MyCell'

Comment: I found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875353/no-visible-view-in-custom-table-view-cell?rq=1 but it still doesn't explain why it works ion one place and not the other...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

[No Visible View in Custom Table View Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17875353/no-visible-view-in-custom-table-view-cell?rq=1)

In the custom uitableviewcell, in the identity inspector assign the Files Owner's class as the view with the table, and override uitableview cell with your custom class

My mistake as trying to re-use the custom class with a second view.

For completeness' sake, minimum code

parent.h

```
#import "blogCellVC.h"

@interface BlogsListingiPhoneVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> 
{
    UITableView *tableView;
    IBOutlet blogCellVC *tableCell;
}
```

parent.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [tableView registerClass: [blogCellVC class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *MyIndentifier = @"MyCell";

    blogCellVC *cell = (blogCellVC *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIndentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[blogCellVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];    
    }

    [cell cellHead:info.blogName];
    [cell cellHeadCol:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [cell cellIcon:@"blank.png"];
    return cell;
}
```

blogCellVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface blogCellVC : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UILabel *cellHead;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *cellIcon;
}

- (void)cellHead:(NSString *)_text;
- (void)cellIcon:(NSString *)_text;
- (void)cellHeadCol:(UIColor *)aCol;

@end
```

blogCellVC.m

```
@interface blogCellVC ()

@end

@implementation blogCellVC

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code.
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"blogCellVC" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Lastly make sure in the xib/storyboard you've put "MyCell" or whatever in the Identifier field in the Attributes Inspector.

This works in X Code 5, ios7